# How to horizontally position button in MUI TextField immediately to the right of the text

Tags: material-ui, textfield, horizontal-alignment

I used the endAdornment prop to insert a button in a TextField.  Even with position set to 'start', the button appears to the far right of the field.  I want it to appear right next to the Text.  I realize that I can place it immediately to the left of the Text using startAdornment.  That is not what I want.

```
                <TextField 
                    value='Text'
                    InputProps={{ 
                        endAdornment: (
                            <InputAdornment position="start">
                            <IconButton>
                                <InfoOutlined />
                            </IconButton>
                            </InputAdornment>
                        )
                    }}
                />
```

I tried using display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'start', justifyItems: 'start', justifySelf: 'start'. None of these effected the alignment.

Comment: The text is within the html `<input>` element which has a particular width. The adornment is placed to the right of that `<input>` element. You won't get the adornment right next to the text unless you resize the `<input>` element to be the same size as the text within it.

Comment: Hi @Andre. You could try using the **multiple** and **renderTags** properties to render a single option as a combination of **option-and-icon**. Although *multiple* is used, the field is set up to only capture a single value. See this [demonstration](https://kofeigen.srht.site/so/so-76240389). If this works for you, I'll post the relevant code as an answer.